# SQL code for identifying if there is a new value

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that I need to set to produce a new page when an id number changes. What is some SQL code to identify when a value changes for a column. Say this column is named ID and it is an arbitrary set of numbers 0000000 format etc, how can I code to know when this number changes?

Comment: You would normally use grouping facility for that, see http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/pagebreaksgroup.htm

Comment: 1. Which type of DataBase are you using? 2. Is the app that will update the DB is the one who should generate the report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need SQL for this.

1. In your report, open your **Group Expert**.  Group your report by your unique ID.  You will now see 2 new sections in your report design, a Group Footer and a Group Header.
2. Open your **Section Expert**.  Click on the Group Header to access the options therein.  Turn on the **New Page Before** option.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done within Crystal Reports.  Perform a grouping on the column, and tell it to apply a new page break after in Section Expert.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is probably better, but if that doesn't work for you, try the Previous() and Next() functions in the Formula editor to see if the value of the field has changed or is about to change.